# Why does this transport-level error occur?

Tags: sql-server, database

After a breakdown on my virtual webhost, they finally restored the container, but now I randomly get the error when I try to execute queries. I can do a

> Select top 20000 from Orders

But

> Select * from Orders (about 100k rows total)

Receives the error in my management studio:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

And this error in my error log:

> A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client. A common cause for this is if the application is running in READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. This connection will be terminated.

I have googled the error and can see that it could be because "Lightweight pooling" is enabled, but this is not the case here.

I run mssql 2008 express on a windows 2003 server.

Comment: Are you running in read uncommitted (or do you have with nolock somewhere)

Comment: Can you point me in a direction on where I can see if I am running in read uncommitted? And if it is in Read Uncommitted mode, what mode should it be set to?

Answer (score 1):

We get the same random issue on MSSQL where I work and (for us any way) its down to network issues (too much traffic and such).

Comment: I have looked at my error log and I get this error: A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client. A common cause for this is if the application is running in READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. This connection will be terminated.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/spike/archive/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx) by [Michael Aspengren](http://blogs.msdn.com/spike/default.aspx) explains the error message "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server."